# Generating a unique value for a header on each $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers

I have a fairly large AngularJS application and for logging purposes, I am being tasked with adding a custom header to all of our HTTP requests from the app that contain **a unique ID for each request.** This really is more valuable to our API calls, but as of now I'm just aiming for all requests (getting templates, styles, etc.)

I am currently using a provider decorator to patch each of the methods exposed by `$HttpProvider` (implementation based on [this post](http://manikanta.com/blog/2013/07/25/decorate-angularjs-http-service-to-convert-put/)), to attempt to call the ID method each time one of those `$http` methods runs, and add the appropriate header:

```
module.config([
  '$provide',
  function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$http', [
      '$delegate',
      function addUniqueIdHeader($http) {
        var httpMethods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete'];

        /**
         * Patched HTTP factory function that adds a request ID each time it is called.
         * @param  {string} method - A valid HTTP method.
         * @return {function} A function that sets various request properties.
         */
        function httpWithHeader(method) {
          return function(url, data, config) {
            config = config || {};
            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            // the magic
            config.headers['My-Custom-Header'] = aUniqueId();

            data = data || {};

            config.method = method.toUpperCase();

            // return `$http` with a modified config, adding the URL and data passed in
            // `_.extend()` is lodash, not underscore.
            return $http(_.extend(config, {
              url: url,
              data: data
            }));
          }
        };

        // back up the orginal methods and patch
        _.each(httpMethods, function (httpMethod) {
          var backupMethod = '_' + httpMethod;

          $http[backupMethod] = $http[httpMethod];
          $http[httpMethod] = httpWithHeader(httpMethod);
        });

        return $http;
      }
    ]);
  }
]);
```

What I have so far works some of the time, but doesn't seem to work consistently (some API requests have it, some don't). I should note that we are using a quite old version of AngularJS (1.0.6) and no, I cannot upgrade (as much as I would love to) so the use of request interceptors is not possible. Additionally, we use Restangular for the majority of our API interactions.

My question is, is using a provider decorator the right way to go? If so, is there a cleaner way to add the header without having to override/patch each individual HTTP method that I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue by utilizing Restangular's [request interceptors](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addfullrequestinterceptor), since the version of Angular we use doesn't have them baked in.